# Load partial from class library

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, renderpartial

Is there a way to load partial views from a class library?
I would like to pull out the common parts from several websites to make them easier to maintain.

Currently I render my partials with (for example)

```
<%Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Search/_searchBlock.ascx", ViewData);%>
```

This is file based, but when creating a class library, the views are compiled.
Is there a way to load libraries that are compiled in this library?

Comment: This seems like a very useful thing to do, especially when migrating an app from WebForms to MVC. Is it possible in more recent versions of asp.net mvc or mvc 2?

Comment: @Ashley. I have seen it used in a tutorial a while ago. But as I'm not working on that project anymore I didn't use it in practice.
If I manage to find it again, I'll post a link later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way i can think to do this would be with [embedded resources](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292) and a custom viewengine. Point reflector (or download the MVC soruce) at System.Web.Mvc.Html.RenderPartialExtensions

Comment: Hmm, is there perhaps a more straightforward way to make controls available in multiple sites?

Comment: Im not sure, I'd be interested if there is. It will be a bit of a job to do it my way, you'll need to replace the call to BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath with something that reads the textstream for you file from the assembly resources, compile it into a ViewUserControl. effort basically

Comment: perhaps svn:externals could help you?

Comment: http://bitworking.org/news/Sourceforge__Subversion_and_svn_externals You could put the shared .ascxs in their own repos and then use svn:externals to reference them from each project

Comment: I fear it's not possible in my current company's setup (don't ask :S ), but it looks like a solution to me. Thx

Comment: @Andrew. This is what I did in the end btw

Answer (score 0):

See Phil Haacks [new post](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/22/scripted-db-views.aspx) for an alternative idea

Comment: He, I was reading it whilst you answered. Appreciate you turning back tho this. Although it does look wicked, I fail to see how this could be of much use in my scenario. I think I'm going to have a stab at creating my own method that locates views. That way I could for example add a appKey that says where they are located and all sites would go pick it up from there rather then searching in it's own folder.

Comment: Its the virtualpathprovider business, thats what you need to override/implement to do what you want

Comment: Hmm, seems the rendering is file based untill deep in the engine :S This sucks.